# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 66029 > 65536

Tags: android, android-build

I am trying to `build` the `apk` from my app but everytime I try and `build` the `apk` I get the following error.

`Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
methods: 66029 > 65536`

#### Build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0-rc1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.warrenedy.julyfinal"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.8'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/jxl.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 5):

Enable multidex in your `build.gradle`.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```